# Permission denied for schema pg_toast while querying sequences

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

The goal is to get the table and column which are "using" a sequence, and the query I've come up with is this:

```sql
select attrelid::regclass::text, attname 
from pg_attribute 
where pg_get_serial_sequence(attrelid::regclass::text, attname) = 'public.websession_idcntr_seq';
```

It's inefficient so any other suggestions are also welcome, but the problem at hand is that this breaks with the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema pg_toast
```

So the next thing I did was try to avoid pg_toast:

```sql
select attrelid::regclass::text, attname 
from pg_attribute 
    join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
    join pg_namespace nsp on tbl.relnamespace = nsp.oid
where 
    nsp.nspname != 'pg_toast'
    and pg_get_serial_sequence(attrelid::regclass::text, attname) = 'public.websession_idcntr_seq';
```

That also fails with exactly the same message.

I have no intention of doing anything with the pg_toast schema, and I can't run this under a superuser account. (EDIT: And I can't modify permissions to get around that).

Why doesn't the workaround with `nspname != 'pg_toast'` work?

Is there a better way to do this whole operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not guarantee you a certain order in which the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are evaluated, and `EXPLAIN` will show you that `pg_get_serial_sequence` (which causes the error) is executed first.

Try the following that excludes the offending tables earlier on:

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass, a.attname
FROM pg_class AS t
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a ON t.oid = a.attrelid
WHERE t.relkind IN ('r', 'p')  /* only normal and partitioned tables */
  AND pg_get_serial_sequence(t.oid::regclass::text, attname)
      = 'public.websession_idcntr_seq';
```

Comment: That's exactly it, I forgot about the ordering! Thanks!